# Как распилить datatable

Tags: c#, wpf, ado.net

Возникла проблема, мне необходимо вывести две спортивные команды, но когда я вывожу их из бд, то выводит одну и ту же команду по миллион раз. Понимаю, что раз я указал в Binding(в нескольких TextBlock-ах) одинаковое название атрибута в сущности из бд, и при этом прошу в запросе вывести мне команды, то он будет пихать во все TextBlock-и одни и те же данные. Но я не могу понять как распилить это, чтобы было красиво и правильно, ибо не хочу писать костыли и портить код.

Это метод из созданного класса "Loader" откуда берется datatable:

```
        private static DataView dv;
        private static DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        private static SqlCommand cmd;
        private static SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

        public static DataView getDataMatches()
        {
            try
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand($"SELECT TeamName, Logo, Starttime, Status, Team_Away_Score, Team_Home_Score, Location FROM Matchup, Team WHERE Matchup.Team_Away = Team.TeamId", con);
                adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
                adapter.Fill(dt);
                return dv = dt.DefaultView;
            }
            catch(SqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Это cs окна:

```
public MatchUp()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //MainWindow wnd = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
            //wnd.setTextHeader(Title.ToString());
            matchUpPlitka.ItemsSource = Loader.getDataMatches();
        }
```

Это xaml окна:

```
<Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="150"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <ItemsControl x:Name="matchupHeader">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                    <Image Width="100" Height="100" Source="{Binding Logo}"/>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                        <TextBlock FontSize="15" FontFamily="Rubik" Text="{Binding TeamName}"/>
                                        <TextBlock FontSize="10" FontFamily="Rubik" Text="(Away)"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                    <TextBlock Text="VS" FontSize="35" FontFamily="Rubik"/>
                                    <TextBlock FontSize="10" FontFamily="Rubik" Text="{Binding Starttime}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                    <Image Width="100" Height="100" Source="{Binding Logo}"/>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                        <TextBlock FontSize="15" FontFamily="Rubik" Text="{Binding TeamName}"/>
                                        <TextBlock FontSize="10" FontFamily="Rubik" Text="(Home)"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </StackPanel>
            
            <ListBox x:Name="matchUpPlitka" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Grid.Row="1">
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1" Width="250" Height="250" Margin="10,10" CornerRadius="10">
                            <Grid>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                            <Image Width="50" Height="50" Source="{Binding Logo}"/>
                                            <TextBlock FontSize="10" FontFamily="Rubik" Text="{Binding TeamName}"/>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                            <TextBlock x:Name="isRunning" Foreground="White" Background="Red" Text="{Binding Status}"/>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                            <Image Width="50" Height="50" Source="{Binding Logo}"/>
                                            <TextBlock FontSize="10" FontFamily="Rubik" Text="{Binding TeamName}"/>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Vertical">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Location}" Margin="0,10,0,10"/>
                                    <Button x:Name="view" Content="View" Width="130" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="view_Click">
                                        <Button.Resources>
                                            <Style TargetType="Border">
                                                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>
                                            </Style>
                                        </Button.Resources>
                                    </Button>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </Grid>
```

Что получается:
[image: Что получилось]

Как должно быть:
[image: Как должно быть]

UPD: Теперь я смог накостылить данный запрос(ниже), но супер много повторений(12к)(всего матчей 299), решил юзнуть DISTINCT, но он плюется на атрибуты Logo, т.к тип данных image, пробовал cast и convert, сократилось до 2к, но все равно есть дубликаты.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.TeamName as Home, t1.Logo as Home_Logo, t2.TeamName as Away, t2.Logo as Away_Logo, m1.Starttime, m1.Status, m1.Team_Away_Score, m1.Team_Home_Score, m1.Location 
FROM Matchup as m1 INNER JOIN Team as t1 on (m1.Team_Home = t1.TeamId), Matchup as m2 INNER JOIN Team as t2 on (m2.Team_Away = t2.TeamId)
```

Также просили схему данных(выделил нужные сущности):

[image: диаграмма бд]

Comment: работайте над SQL запросом, чтобы в каждой строке его результата были обе команды, а не только одна

Comment: Покажите структуру данных таблиц БД

Comment: @aepot скриншот диаграммы? или ER диаграмму? сразу скажу ER нет, лень делать, она супер большая

Comment: @aepot но кажется я нашел решение, при SELECTнаписать два раза teamname и с помощью AS назвать TeamHome и TeamAway, с условием, типо, команда HOME идет в 1 колонку и наоборот

Comment: SQL код разметки таблицы, где видно типы и имена полей.

Comment: @aepot это сформировать скрипт? что-то не могу нахухлить код разметки

Comment: Table schema...

Comment: @aepot good....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смог в итоге напилить запрос, мб кому-то в будущем понадобиться, так сказать оставил наследие. В итоге все работает и выводит по красоте, осталось допилить. В общем и целом тут два `INNER JOIN`. Самое главное, посмотрите на второй `JOIN`. Там я `переименовал` сущность `Team` в `t`, после указал, что другие атрибуты должны быть с `t`.

```
SELECT Team.TeamName as Home, Team.Logo as LogoHome, Team_Home_Score, t.TeamName as Away, t.Logo as LogoAway, Team_Away_Score, Starttime, Location, Status 
FROM Matchup INNER JOIN Team on (Team_Home = TeamId) INNER JOIN Team as t on (Team_Away = t.TeamId)
```

[image]